# How to create a random matrix such that all rows sum to 1

Tags: matlab, matrix

Here is what the matrix would look like:

There are 8 columns and say 100 rows, the random numbers in any row sum to 1.

> .125 .125 .125 .125 ....... .125
>
> .005 .105 .005 .205 ....... .205
>
> .002 .003 .012. 201 ....... .200
>
> ...

Could Matlab automatically creates this kind of matrix, i.e. a [right stochastic matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix)? I am looking for a script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `bsxfun` rather than `repmat`:

```
mat = rand(100, 8);
rowsum = sum(mat,2);
mat = bsxfun(@rdivide, mat, rowsum);
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's another idea: for each row you could generate 7 random numbers (between 0 and 1) and treat those as your "interval" locations - in other words, in your 8 random numbers that sum to 1, these are your partial sums. Then you can sort them and take the differences to get your resulting random numbers. Here is code for what I'm thinking:

```
numrows = 100;
partialsums = [zeros(numrows,1), rand(numrows,7), ones(numrows,1)];
partialsums = sort(partialsums, 2);
randmat = diff(partialsums, 1, 2);
```

The distribution of the numbers is going to be different depending the way you do it. I compared this method to the one posted by Aabaz, and I got this for distributions.

[image]

So mine looks a little more exponential, you get some higher values, and his is a little more uniform, but with a lower cutoff of random numbers that you get.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that there are different ways resulting in different distributions.

Answer (score 4):

You can first create your random matrix and then normalize it so that every row has a sum that is equal to 1 (if that is what you meant):

```
mat=rand(100,8);
matnorm=repmat(sum(mat,2),1,8);
mat=mat./matnorm;
```

Answer (score 1):

step 1: Calculate the norm of the vector, which is the square root of the sum of the square of the elements in that vector.

step 2: Divide each element in the vector by the norm of the vector.

step 3: Multiply the resulting vector by its transpose to square each element in the vector.

You can then see that the sum of the (final) resulting elements in the vector add up to 1.

Answer (score -2):

Well

```
rand(100,8)
```

will generate a matrix of random numbers with 100 rows and 8 columns all of whose entries can be added to 1.  If that doesn't do what you want, you'll have to explain yourself a bit more.

Comment: -1 That creates a matrix of random numbers, each distributed between 0 and 1. The rows don't sum to 1, which is what the asker requested.