# Find cumulative proportion of simulations that meet condition

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, cumulative-sum

I have a matrix *A* (100,5) where each row is the result of a simulation (n=100).

I would like to plot / 'record' the cumulative proportions of simulations where the maximum value in *A* is less than 0.40.  The plot I am envisioning has vertical axis where the values range from 0 to 100% and the horizontal axis is the number of simulations.

Ultimately I be plotting several scenarios on the same graph where at least one will reach the 100% cumulative proportion at the 100 simulations mark exactly.

The code below is how far I have gotten, but I am having trouble getting the cumulative proportion thing down.  I don't think that my matrix *C* is what I am looking for.

Cheers.

```
ts=1:1:100;
% Create A where all rows sum to 1
A = rand(100, 5); % @Nzbuu http://stackoverflow.com/q/9312850/1670053 for this ex 
rowsum = sum(A,2);
A = bsxfun(@rdivide, A, rowsum);

% Create a vector from A where each elements records whether the max value was less 
% than 0.40 (value = 0) or greater than 0.40 (value = 1)
counts = zeros(100,1);
for i = 1:100
    if max(A(i,:)) < 0.40
        counts(i) = 0;
    else
        counts(i) = 1;
    end;
end;

B = cumsum(counts); % Get the cumulative sum of counts
C = B/100
plot(ts, C)
```

Comment: Based on your description this looks correct. What reason do you have for thinking C is not what you're after? Is it because it never goes to 100%? The way you're creating your stochastic matrix A is such that the expected value in each element is 1/5 = 0.2, thus a value >0.4 is not likely.

Comment: There will a few values in counts that are equal to zero. This would mean the highest value of B is less than 100. Therefore the graph would not reach 100%, but would reach the percent of rows > 0.4. Also you could do counts = max(A, 2) >= 0.4; instead of doing the for loop.

Comment: @jerad thanks, for the confirmation.  I won't be using this matrix in my actual pursuit, so perhaps its newness added to my self-doubt.  @ Pavan thanks for the non-for-loop method too.