# Why this thing happens with random matrix such that all rows sum up to 1?

Tags: matlab, precision

I would like to generate a random matrix whose rows sum up to one. I found this question and answers [How to create a random matrix such that all rows sum to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312850/how-to-create-a-random-matrix-such-that-all-rows-sum-to-1) which do what I exactly want.

The problem is when I did it, sometimes the sum is not exactly one.

```
mat      = rand(2, 2);
rowsum   = sum(mat, 2);
mat      = bsxfun(@rdivide, mat, rowsum);
```

Sometimes I get something like this:

```
sum_test = sum(mat, 2)-1
1.0e-15 *
      0
-0.2220;
```

I do not know why?

Comment: You get this because a double has a limited precision: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab uses double-precision numbers, which means there are only a finite set of numbers that can be represented. The gap between double-precision numbers can be found in Matlab using the `eps` function. For a value of 1, which is pretty much the value you get when you sum up each row, `eps(1) = 2.220446049250313e-16`, which is the same magnitude numerical error you're getting. The error is introduced when you divide each value in the matrix. More information about Matlab precision [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html).

Even doing something like subtracting the error from the first value in each row doesn't solve your problem completely (although it does help). For example,

```
mat = rand(10,10);
rowsum = sum(mat,2);
mat = bsxfun(@rdivide,mat,rowsum);
sum_test = sum(mat,2)-1    %finite error
mat(:,1) = mat(:,1) - sum_test; %subtract the error from the first column in each row
sum_test2 = sum(mat,2)-1   %still get error
```

results in

```
sum_test = [
-1.110223024625157e-16
                     0
                     0
                     0
                     0
-2.220446049250313e-16
                     0
-2.220446049250313e-16
-1.110223024625157e-16
-2.220446049250313e-16]
```

and

```
sum_test2 = [
 2.220446049250313e-16
                     0
                     0
                     0
                     0
                     0
                     0
                     0
-1.110223024625157e-16
                     0]
```

(You can show that even `(sum(mat,2)-0.5)-0.5` gives a different answer than `sum(mat,2)-1`)